# SQL Query - INSERT INTO with SELECT WHERE does nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 tables with the same schema already created. I want to insert rows from table1 -> table2 with the constraint of Age(column) not being duplicates. The query executes but nothing gets inserted.

```
CREATE TABLE #Global (dbName varchar(100) NULL)
INSERT INTO #Global VALUES ('db1')

DECLARE @temp nvarchar(1000)
SELECT @temp = dbName from #Global

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SELECT @sql = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Person] ([age], [name])
              SELECT [age], [name]
              FROM [' + @temp + ']..[Person] 
              WHERE [Person].[age] <> [' + @temp + ']..[Person].[age]'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you test the `SELECT` statement to see if data is returned?

Comment: Radu - yeah the select statement works

Comment: I don't see how the `SELECT` statement could possibly work - you're comparing Person.age to some other expression which, as a human, I can see is trying to pick out stuff from another database's table, but SQL Server couldn't possibly interpret this. Also, some of the answers have given you what you possibly want (one row per age with an arbitrarily chosen name & ID) but it's not what you actually asked for (do you mean you want to exclude anyone who has the same age as anyone else?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write as:

```
CREATE TABLE #Global (dbName varchar(100) NULL)
INSERT INTO #Global VALUES ('db1')

DECLARE @temp nvarchar(1000)
SELECT @temp = dbName from #Global

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SELECT @sql = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Person] ([age], [name])
              SELECT [age], [name]
              FROM [' + @temp + '].[Person] 
              WHERE [' + @temp + '].[Person].[age] NOT IN (SELECT [age] from [dbo].[Person])'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

**Why your where clause is not working?
Schema scope resolution always starts at the user’s default schema and revert to the
dbo schema if the referenced object is not scope-qualified.**

In the where clause you have not specified schema name for first table. So it's taken as DB1 the source table itself. Just try replacing it with [dbo] schema and whole statement will give you syntax error. Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Deepshikha - thanks for the correct solution and explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Your where clause would exclude all rows.

You should try something like this:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SELECT @sql = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Person] ([id], [age], [name])
              SELECT min([id]) as id, [age], min([name]) as name
              FROM [' + @temp + ']..[Person] 
              group by age'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: muhmud - I can't seem to get your code to work. It inserts the entire table1 into table2

Comment: Are you sure? If you do a `select count(distinct Age) from Person` does this return the same number as `select count(*) from Person`?

Comment: Try running the select by itself, without dynamic sql; do the results look right?

Answer (score 0):

try this as the select statement:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Person] ([age], [name])
SELECT [age], [name]
FROM [' + @temp + ']..[Person] 
WHERE [' + @temp + ']..[Person].[age] 
not in (select distinct age from [dbo].[Person])
```